# Junit 5 - @DisplayNameGenerator - Not working in Terminal

Tags: java, junit, annotations, junit5

I've searched everywhere for a step by step explanation for this but to no avail. The requirement is simple and clear

1. I have a demo test class in AppTest.java and I am using Junit 5 for this
2. I am using the @DisplayNameGenerator with a custom Generator static class
3. But no changes are showing in the termnial

I am not sure what it is I need to do further. Can someone help me please?
Here is the code so far I have got:

```
package learnjunit;

/* assertions and junit 5 core annotation imports */
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


@DisplayNameGeneration(AppTest.ReplaceCamelCase.class)
public class AppTest {
  @BeforeAll
  public static void test_beforeAll() {
    System.out.println("@BeforeAll - Executing");
  }

  @BeforeEach
  public void test_beforeEach() {
    System.out.println("@Before - Executing");
  }

  @Test  
  public void test_testOne() {
    System.out.println("@Test - Executing for test_testOne()");
  }

  @Test
  public void test_testTwo() {
    System.out.println("@Test - Executing for test_testTwo()");
  }

  @AfterEach  
  public void test_afterEach() {
    System.out.println("@AfterEach - Executing");
  }

  @AfterAll
  public static void test_afterAll() {
    System.out.println("@AfterAll - Executing");
  }
  
  static class ReplaceCamelCase extends DisplayNameGenerator.Standard {
      @Override
      public String generateDisplayNameForClass(Class<?> testClass) {
          /* -> this I can see in the terminal */ System.out.println(super.generateDisplayNameForClass(testClass));
          /* -> this has no effect */ return super.generateDisplayNameForClass(testClass) + "__YES";
      }

      @Override
      public String generateDisplayNameForNestedClass(Class<?> nestedClass) {
          return replaceCamelCase(super.generateDisplayNameForNestedClass(nestedClass));
      }

      @Override
      public String generateDisplayNameForMethod(Class<?> testClass, Method testMethod) {
          return this.replaceCamelCase(testMethod.getName()) + 
            DisplayNameGenerator.parameterTypesAsString(testMethod);
      }

      String replaceCamelCase(String camelCase) {
          StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
          result.append(camelCase.charAt(0));
          for (int i=1; i<camelCase.length(); i++) {
              if (Character.isUpperCase(camelCase.charAt(i))) {
                  result.append(' ');
                  result.append(Character.toLowerCase(camelCase.charAt(i)));
              } else {
                  result.append(camelCase.charAt(i));
              }
          }
          return result.toString();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for me when I run your code in IntelliJ IDEA. That is, the listener that IDEA uses to collect the test results shows your names. How are you running the tests?

Comment: I am running all of this using terminal only

Comment: What command line exactly are you using?

Comment: i am using the command mvn test

Comment: Can you provide your pom file as well?